Алгоритм разбиения полигонов с отверстиями на простые многоугольники
У меня есть области двумерной плоскости, ограниченные многоугольниками, они могут быть невыпуклыми и содержать отверстия (кольца). Мне нужен алгоритм, который разобьет эти многоугольники на простые (то есть полигоны без самопересечений и отверстий). Я нашел статью, в которой ссылаются на разбиение через алгоритм sweep-line, но никаких деталей, о том, как это должно работать нет.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_triangulation#Triangulating_a_non-monotone_polygon
Возможно, вы знаете точное название (или описание) алгоритма, который будет делать то что мне нужно


Ну всем или почти всем алгоритмам триангуляции как бы всё равно, выпуклый ли полигон и есть ли в нём дырки. А потом объединяй полученные треугольники так, чтобы не получить "самопересечений и отверстий".

@Akina, алгоритмы триангуляции требуют многоугольник без дырок.

Ограничений по времени нет. Перебирайте вершины на дырке, вершины на внешней границе, соединяйте отрезком, проверяйте что отрезок есть диагональ. За N^4 удалите все дырки.

@StanislavVolodarskiy не думаю, что здесь подойдет наивная реализация, посмотрите на картинку в примере

Наивная реализация работает всегда. За N^3 вы переберёте все диагонали и удалите одну дырку. Есть теорема, что такая диагональ существует, наивный метод её отыщет. Если говорить всю правду, то за N^4 вы построите этим методом триангуляцию и без удаления дырок. Но я о другом: без требований к производительности постановка задачи не полна.

@StanislavVolodarskiy Полигон с дырками запросто приводится к полигону без дырок. Берём любую вершину любой дырки, которая "видит" хотя бы одну вершину внешнего полигона. Соединяем двумя совпадающими рёбрами (туда-сюда), можно даже удвоить соединяемые вершины. Итог - мы избавились от одной дырки, и присоединили её к полигону. Повторяем, пока не привяжем к полигону все дырки. Триангулируем.

@Akina, не вижу, чем ваш алгоритм отличается от моего.

@StanislavVolodarskiy Ну формально ничем - если не считать того, что наивный N^3 мне лично не нравится. Например, самая "правая" из вершин дырок (или любая из них) непременно образует диагональ с по крайней мере одной из вершин фигуры, располагающихся ещё правее. А это уже N^2.
